# implementing BFS using STL in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, stl, iterator

I am trying to write a code for BFS in c++ using STL. This is the section of the code i am having trouble with

```
std::list<int> li=*i;
for (std::list<int>::iterator iter=li.begin(); iter!=li.end();++iter)
{
  if (arr[iter]==0)
  {
    myQ.push(iter);
    arr[iter]=1;
```

Here arr is the array that stores whether or not i have seen the node .i am getting the error
"No match for operator arr[] in `arr[iter]`

Comment: What is the definition of `arr`?

Comment: The question is about `arr`, yet you didn't post what the definition of `arr` is.

Comment: iter is an iterator, so a kind of poitner, not an integer.  This will cause trouble in your arr[], unless it's defined as a map.

Comment: `std::list<int> li=*i;` this copies the whole list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iter is an iterator, so a kind of pointer, not an integer.  THis is whiy arr[] does not work, because it expects an integer.

Try with `arr[*iter]` instead, and your breadth first search will avoid the cycles succesfully.

Please note that you have the same potential issue with your push(iter), if myQ is supposed to contain nodes as well.

You could further improve your design, by defining arr as a set instead of an array/vector.
Your condition would then look like:

```
if (arr.count(*iter) == 0)  {
    myQ.push_back(*iter);
    arr.insert(*iter);  // works for int, but also other data types
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Iam answering by assuming arr in an integer array.
Any array elemet can be accessed by its integer index only,but not address of integer index.
Here iter is the pointer which can store the address of an integer.

So you have to use '*' to retrieve the value stored at the address to get integer value.

So change array[iter] to array[*iter]..

Hope this will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here iter is an iterator which is pointer to the list, so for accessing its value you have to write *iter(access value which it is pointing) instead of iter(it is reference).

Try this

```
std::list<int> li=*i;
for (std::list<int>::iterator iter=li.begin(); iter!=li.end();++iter)
{
    if (arr[*iter]==0)
    {
       myQ.push(*iter);
       arr[*iter]=1;
```